# Regex number range for numbers preceding with zeros

Tags: regex

How do I form a regex to validate a range from 1 to 1000, where the number 001 is same as 1, 0245 is same as 245. Most solutions I saw allowed the range check but did not allow the number to start with 0. The problem is with not allowing 0,00,000, but allow the number to start with or without 0.

Edit: it should allow 1,01,001 and not any number exceeding 4 digits.

Comment: I have a feeling this is more about your specific regexp implementation than about regular expressions in general: just put `0{0-1}` in front of the rest of your expression...?

Comment: Why are you not using normal language facilities?

Comment: @tchrist I've to validate a value and the validation framework provides validation in form of number range validation (which is contiguous), character validation .... regex validation. I have to check if the value lies within specific range segments which are not contiguous.

Comment: I feel as though the accepted answer is not the answer you are looking for. The accepted answer will allow 00000, and will allow 000000000000000000000000, and 00009999. My impression is that you would like to **disallow** these.

Comment: @Wesley - I addressed this point in the comments on my answer. My understanding was that leading zeroes should not count toward the 4-digit limit; the point is to match numbers between 1 and 1000, and 001000 still satisfies that. However, as I mentioned, inserting `(?=\d{1,4}$)` after the `^` in my answer will restrict it to 4 characters.

Comment: @Wesley - Also, please note that 00000 and other all-zero patterns won't match because of the `[1-9]`.

Comment: @Justin Morgan: Sorry, I've misread the question. You're right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do this. My first thought is something like this:

```
/^0*(1000|[1-9]\d{0,2})$/
```

Explanation:

The `0*` consumes any leading zeroes. After that, you're looking for either 1000 or a 1- to 3-digit number that doesn't start with zero. The `[1-9]` requires that at least one nonzero digit is present, and the `\d{0,2}` allows up to two digits after that (so numbers ending in zero are still allowed).

Comment: This is probably the simplest correct answer. Original question wasn't clear on whether regexp is checked against individual numerical strings, or used to extract matching numbers from strings, but it sounds like the former.

Comment: It works fine. How does a number like 203 pass with 0 in middle?

Comment: @Rnet: A `0` in the middle is matched by `\d`

Comment: This solution does allow also 0001000, shouldn't there be a  maximum of 4 digits?

Comment: @stema - If I understood the requirement, leading 0s don't matter. If they do, `^(?=\d{1,4}$)` at the beginning should take care of it.

Comment: @Justin That was my understanding and the reason I added also an answer after reading yours ;-)

Comment: Good answer. +1 (and thanks Justin for pointing out the flaw in my lame late-night attempt.)

Comment: @ridgerunner - No problem, I've seen you around and I know you've got regex skillz. :)

Answer (score 2):

`^(1000|0?[1-9][0-9][0-9]|0{0,2}[1-9][0-9]|0{0,3}[1-9])$`,
or equivalent
`^(1000|0?[1-9]\d{2}|0{0,2}[1-9]\d|0{0,3}[1-9])$`
will do the trick: all from 0001 to 1000 with or without leading 0's but no more than 4 digits:

- 1st group: only 1000, no leading 0's
- 2nd group: 100-999, up to 1 leading 0
- 3rd group: 10-99, up to 2 leading 0's
- 4th group: 1-9, up to 3 leading 0's

Answer (score 2):

What about this here:

```
^(1000|(?=\d{1,4})0*[1-9]\d{0,2})$
```

This is to my opinion the shortest solution, that restricts the maximum allowed digits to 4 and the maximum number to 1000.

I check the start and the end with anchors to prevent that there is something else. Then check for 1000. The second part is then the different one.

`(?=\d{1,4})`is a zero length lookahead assertion. That means a non consuming thing that just checks if there are between 1 and 4 numbers. If this is true then continue, else no match. Then just check if there is something with leading 0's and up to 3 numbers at the end.

This can be checked online here: [http://regexr.com](http://regexr.com?2tht9)

Answer (score 0):

myregexp.com

regexp: `^(0+)?(?=\d{1,4})([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|1000)$`

0001000 matches
0001001 doesn't match
0..1000 matches
anything above 1000 doesn't match

Comment: Just FYI, your `[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]` is equivalent to `[1-9]\d{0,2}`. Could help shorten this up.

Comment: The `(?=\d{1,4})` also appears to be redundant if I'm not mistaken, and `(0+)?` is the same as `0*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^((1000)|(0\d{1,3})|(\d{1,3}))$/
```

Matches

```
1000
100
0001
01
1
010
0010
0100
```

Does not match

```
10000
00001
```

Proof available at https://regex101.com/r/MIScKF/1

Comment: I believe that would still match 0, 00, 000, or 0000.

Comment: Yep, but those are still valid values.

Comment: I don't think so. The question describes a range of 1 to 1000, and I read the second-last sentence as wanting to disallow 0, 00, and 000. BTW, your `(0\d{1,3})|(\d{1,3})` could be rewritten as `0?\d{1,3}`.

Comment: You're right! I miss-read the last statement. I had read it as allowing 0, 00, etc.